What are "terms" in the Master Theorem?
The following is part of the proof for the Master Theorem for divide-and-conquer recursive algorithms
If $a=b^d$ and $n$ is a power of $b$ then:
$$f(n)=n^df(1)+cn^d\log_bn$$
We show this with $k=\log_bn$, it follows that:$$f(n)=a^kf(1)+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a^jc(n/b^j)^d=a^kf(1)+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}cn^d=$$$$=a^kf(1)+kcn^d=a^{log_bn}f(1)+c(\log_bn)n^d=n^{\log_ba}f(1)+cn^d\log_bn=$$$$=n^df(1)+cn^d\log_bn$$
This means that if $a=b^d$, then $f(n)$ is $O(n^d\log n)$ since the 2nd term dominates the first.
I'm confused on what they mean by "terms", what are they referring to when they say "the 2nd term dominates the first"?

By first term, I presume the author means $n^d f(1)$ and likewise for the second. Remember - plus and minus signs separate terms.

Ok I see that now, thank you!

I got my answer from Sean Roberson's comment, thank you!
By terms, they mean in $n^df(1)+cn^d\log_bn$, the 1st term would be $=n^df(1)$ and the 2nd term would be $cn^d\log_bn$.
